# How can i Assign onkeypress-function to dynamically created input-boxes in javascript?

Tags: javascript

How can i Assign onkeypress-function to dynamically created input-boxes in javascript ?

You can find my source code here: http://goo.gl/9BHSt

```
var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
var el = document.createElement('input');
el.type = 'text';
el.size = "3";
el.name = 'txtUnit' + iteration;
el.id = 'txtUnit' + iteration;
el.onKeyPress = "return checkIt(event)";                       
cell2.appendChild(el);   
el.type = 'text';
el.size = "3";
el.name = 'txtUnit' + iteration;
el.id = 'txtUnit' + iteration;
el.onKeyPress = "return checkIt(event)";                       
cell2.appendChild(el);
```

But 
`el.onKeyPress = "return checkIt(event)";`  is not working . Why ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use this :

```
el.onkeypress = 
   function(event)
   {
      //write your method body
   };
```

or

```
el.onkeypress = KeyPressHandler;
function KeyPressHandler(event)
{
   //write your method body
}
```

**EDIT**

You have provided wrong argument. see this :

```
function KeyPressHandler(event)
{
   evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event
   var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode
   if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
      status = "This field accepts numbers only."
      return false;
   }
   status = ""
   return true;
}
```

you should change parameter name to **evt**

```
function KeyPressHandler(evt)
{
   evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event
   var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode
   if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
      status = "This field accepts numbers only."
      return false;
   }
   status = ""
   return true;
}
```

I tested, and It worked fine.

Comment: Hi,
I tried the above method .. But not working,,
Sorce code : http://dl.dropbox.com/u/7384181/test_keypress.html
For second input box was not calling the function .. :(

Answer (score 0):

You'll be better off using jQuery. It has a `live` function which allows to attach events to dynamically added elements.